# Calculate Grouped Median if you have an numeric interval

Tags: python, pandas, intervals, median

This is my dataframe with interval numbers (classes) in it.

```
     df = pd.DataFrame({'Class': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], 
               'Class Interval': ['16.25-18.75', '18.75-21.25', '21.25-23.75', 
                                  '23.75-26.25', '26.25-28.75', '28.75-31.25',
                                  '31.25-33.75', '33.75-36.25', '36.25-38.75',
                                  '38.75-41.25', '41.25-43.75'],
              '' : [2,7,7,14,17,24,11,11,3,3,1],
              'Cumulative ': [2,9,16,30,47,71,82,93,96,99,100],
              '/n' : [.02,.07,.07,.14,.17,.24,.11,.11,.03,.03,.01],
              'Cumulative /n' : [.02, .09,.16,.30,.47,.71,.82,.93,.96,.99,1.00]})
    df

        Class   Class Interval      Cumulative       /    Cumulative  / 
    0   1       16.25-18.75      2          2            0.02   0.02
    1   2       18.75-21.25      7          9            0.07   0.09
    2   3       21.25-23.75      7         16            0.07   0.16
    3   4       23.75-26.25     14         30            0.14   0.30
    4   5       26.25-28.75     17         47            0.17   0.47
    5   6       28.75-31.25     24         71            0.24   0.71
    6   7       31.25-33.75     11         82            0.11   0.82
    7   8       33.75-36.25     11         93            0.11   0.93
    8   9       36.25-38.75     3          96            0.03   0.96
    9   10      38.75-41.25     3          99            0.03   0.99
    10  11      41.25-43.75     1         100            0.01   1.00
```

Question: How can I calculate with python the grouped median for this dataframe?

Manually this can be done and the outcome is 29.06.

I've tried 'median_grouped':

```
    # importing median_grouped from the statistics module 
    from statistics import median_grouped

    # printing median_grouped for the set 
    print("Grouped Median is %s" %(median_grouped(df['Class Interval'])))
```

But I got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-491000133032> in <module>
      4 
      5 # printing median_grouped for the set
----> 6 print("Grouped Median is %s" %(median_grouped(df['Class Interval'])))

~\Anaconda3\ANACONDA\lib\statistics.py in median_grouped(data, interval)
    463     for obj in (x, interval):
    464         if isinstance(obj, (str, bytes)):
--> 465             raise TypeError('expected number but got %r' % obj)
    466     try:
    467         L = x - interval/2  # The lower limit of the median interval.

TypeError: expected number but got '28.75-31.25'
```

Than I've tried to make two columns (one with the lower limit and one with the higher limit), but than he only gave me the lower limit (28.75) / higher limit median (31.25). I've also tried only the lower limit, but of course than he gives me 28.75 as well.

I do not have the values within the intervals, so I can not remake a list of values to cut with pd.cut and try it like that correctly (I do not want to guess), but I've also tried to manually make the class interval into bins (for example 16.25-18.25 is than (16.25,18.25], but than I got the error message: TypeError: unorderable types: Interval() < float()

Is there a possibility to make the column with the interval numeric in stead of a string to be able to calculate the grouped Median automatically with Python?

Comment: Can you explain how do you do it manually? we can reproduce your manual operations

Comment: Calculate the median for grouped data of the dataframe 'df'

The formula for this --> =+(.5−)
where:

 = lower class limit of the interval that contains the median
 = total frequency,
 = the sum of frequencies (cumulative frequency) for all classes before the median class,
 = frequency of the class interval containing the median
 = interval width
Solution

 = 28.75
 = 100
 = 47
 = 24
 = 2.5
So the formula would be: =28.75+2.524(.5∗100−47) = 28.75+0.10416667(50−47) = 28.75+0.3125 = 29.0625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate a list of artificial data points holding the same statistical information (middle value of each interval * *fi* of the interval), and run the `mean_grouped` function in them:

```
# Obtaining lower, upper and middle interval value
df['lower'] = df['Class Interval'].str.split('-', expand=True)[0].astype(float)
df['upper'] = df['Class Interval'].str.split('-', expand=True)[1].astype(float)
df['middle'] = (df['lower'] + df['upper'] ) / 2

# Generating an artificial list of values with the same statistical info
artificial_data_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  artificial_data_list.append([row['middle']]*row[''])
flat_list = [item for sublist in artificial_data_list for item in sublist]

# Calcuating the right median with the statistics.mean_grouped function
median_grouped(flat_list,interval=2.5)   # Attention to the interval size!
# => 29.0625
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd first convert your intervals to two separate columns for `lower bound` (lb) and `upper bound` (ub)

```
df = (df.join(df['Class Interval'].str.split('-', expand=True)
                                  .apply(pd.to_numeric)
                                  .rename(columns={0: 'lb', 1: 'ub'}))
        .drop('Class Interval', 1))
```

Then, looks like you can simply write out the formula straight away

[image]

```
m = len(df)//2
gmedian = df.loc[m, 'lb'] + ((df[''].sum()/2 - df.loc[m - 1, 'Cumulative '])/(df.loc[m, '']))*(df['ub'] - df['lb']).loc[m]
```

Or, in a more didactic way,

```
L = df.loc[m, 'lb']
N = df[''].sum()
F = df.loc[m - 1, 'Cumulative ']
f = df.loc[m, '']
C = (df['ub'] - df['lb']).loc[m]
```

---

```
gmedian = L + ((N/2 - F)/(f))*C
```

Outputs

```
29.0625
```